# Add Certificate to IOS Keychain in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

im trying to write a root certificate to my apps keychain so that I can talk to a server serving up a self signed cert.

```
class func setCertificate(certData: NSData, forKey keyName: String) -> Bool
    {
        var secCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, certData)

        var keychainQueryDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = self.setupKeychainQueryDictionaryForKey(keyName)

        keychainQueryDictionary[kSecClassCertificate as NSString] = secCert.takeRetainedValue()

        // Protect the keychain entry so it's only valid when the device is unlocked
        keychainQueryDictionary[SecAttrAccessible] = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked

        // Disable icloud sync of keychain data
        keychainQueryDictionary[kSecAttrSynchronizable as NSString] = kCFBooleanFalse

        let status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQueryDictionary, nil)

        println(status)

        if status == errSecSuccess
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

But the OSStatus returned is -50 (One or more parameters passed to a function where not valid.), i've tried numerous casts etc but not getting anywhere. The certificate is definitely valid as SecCertificateCreateWithData would return nil if there was an issue with its format.

This is my function for setting up the keychain query

```
private class func setupKeychainQueryDictionaryForKey(keyName: String) -> NSMutableDictionary
    {
        // Setup dictionary to access keychain and specify we are using a generic password (rather than a certificate, internet password, etc)
        var keychainQueryDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = [SecClass:kSecClassGenericPassword]

        // Uniquely identify this keychain accessor
        keychainQueryDictionary[SecAttrService] = KeychainManager.serviceName

        // Uniquely identify the account who will be accessing the keychain
        var encodedIdentifier: NSData? = keyName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        keychainQueryDictionary[SecAttrGeneric] = encodedIdentifier

        keychainQueryDictionary[SecAttrAccount] = encodedIdentifier

        return keychainQueryDictionary
    }
```

Has anyone done this in swift or any advice from anyone?

Cheers

Comment: I'm interested in doing this as well; did you find a solution? Also, are you creating the self-signed certificate using iOS code? If yes, I'm curious to know how. I found a solution using OpenSSL and I believe it is not possible using only Apple APIs, but I may of course have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found what is going wrong with Adrian's code. I found this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/CertGet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH224-SW1) which is from Apple and very useful.

For adding certificate in keychain we have to write following lines:

```
let secCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certInDer as CFData) // certInDer is Certificate(.der) data
        var keychainQueryDictionary = [String : Any]()

        if let tempSecCert = secCert {
            keychainQueryDictionary = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassCertificate, kSecValueRef as String : tempSecCert, kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"]
        }

        let summary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(secCert!)! as String
        print("Cert summary: \(summary)")

        let status = SecItemAdd(keychainQueryDictionary as CFDictionary, nil)

        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        print("success")
```

Hopefully it helps everyone...